# Docker Container Communication

Tags: security, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers that talk to each other through open ports. But say I have (website container)Domain.com/api -> 5000:5001 (api container) so the website takes a request and tells the api to do some work. I am concerned since they are both hosted on the same domain the website is just an abstraction/entry point so a user instead of doing Domain.com/api they can do Domain.com:5001/api to essentially go directly to the api container. Here is an example docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  api-service:
  build: ./nlpapi
  ports:
    - 5001:80

  website-service:
    build: ./tweetnlpwebsite
    volumes:
      - ./tweetnlpwebsite:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - api-service
```

I am new to docker but my understanding of this file is, the docker host has two containers by connecting to docker host through port 5001 you get port 80 of the web container and it shows the page. By connecting to the host through 5000 you can cURL it a request and it will respond since the api container is exposed on that port.

How can I make it so that these containers can talk to each other internally securely and only make request/access the web service?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user-defined network for `website-service` and `api-service` to communicate with each other, and then only publish `website-service` to the outside world.

```
version: '3'
services:
  api-service:
    build: ./nlpapi
    networks:
      - app

  website-service:
    build: ./tweetnlpwebsite
    volumes:
      - ./tweetnlpwebsite:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    depends_on:
      - api-service
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  - app
```

Now, `website-service` can reach `api-service` at `api-service:80`, but the outside world can't access `api-service` directly.

Comment: Docker Compose creates a private network for you automatically; you don't actually need any of the `networks:` blocks.  The important thing is that you configure `website-service` (preferably via an environment variable) to talk to `http://api-service` (if it were listening on something other than the default HTTP port 80, with its internal port number).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Huang,  I was just reading the documentation and came to the same conclusion here https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/. I will be sure to accept your answer when the time limit is up.

Comment: @DavidMaze Do you have any resources on that subject?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ would be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, it's true that the Compose file as originally written will result in a network named `default` being created. I've found that it's not always obvious to everyone, so I've made it a habit to explicitly name all networks.